# CiviCRM on Wordpress - CiviCase will not enable

Tags: mysql, wordpress, civicrm

I am trying to enable CiviCase in my CiviCRM + Wordpress install (I can't seem to find a standalone installation of CiviCRM). However, when I go through the enable process in `Administer > Administration Console > Configuration Checklist > Enable components`, it tells me that:

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.

DB Error: no such field
```

Could someone please tell me how to rectify this? Would I need to manually create tables / fields in my MySQL database?  If so, what fields would I need to create?  I am using CiviCRM 4.4.6 with Wordpress 3.9.2.

**EDIT**

Here is the full error message I receive (debugging enabled):

```
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -19
    [message] => DB Error: no such field
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO `civicrm_option_value` (  `option_group_id`, `label`, `value`, `name`, `grouping`, `filter`, `is_default`, `weight`, `description`, `is_optgroup`, `is_reserved`, `is_active`)
(SELECT @option_group_id_case_type, 'Housing Support',  @max_val + 1, 'housing_support', NULL, 0,  0, @max_wt + 1, 'Help homeless individuals obtain temporary and long-term housing', 0, 0, 1
 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `civicrm_option_value`  WHERE `name` = 'housing_support')) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'label' in 'field list']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT INTO `civicrm_option_value` (  `option_group_id`, `label`, `value`, `name`, `grouping`, `filter`, `is_default`, `weight`, `description`, `is_optgroup`, `is_reserved`, `is_active`)
(SELECT @option_group_id_case_type, 'Housing Support',  @max_val + 1, 'housing_support', NULL, 0,  0, @max_wt + 1, 'Help homeless individuals obtain temporary and long-term housing', 0, 0, 1
 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `civicrm_option_value`  WHERE `name` = 'housing_support')) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'label' in 'field list']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO `civicrm_option_value` (  `option_group_id`, `label`, `value`, `name`, `grouping`, `filter`, `is_default`, `weight`, `description`, `is_optgroup`, `is_reserved`, `is_active`)
(SELECT @option_group_id_case_type, 'Housing Support',  @max_val + 1, 'housing_support', NULL, 0,  0, @max_wt + 1, 'Help homeless individuals obtain temporary and long-term housing', 0, 0, 1
 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `civicrm_option_value`  WHERE `name` = 'housing_support')) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'label' in 'field list']"]
)
```

Would I need to insert that information manually?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing everything right, but it's hard to know exactly what problem you've got without the error details.  If you go to Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling and turn debugging on, and then try again, you'll see the detailed database error from MySQL.

Comment: Done and added the debugging code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how the "label" field is missing from your civicrm_option_value table.  All I can guess is that maybe you tried upgrading from a previous version without running the database upgrade step.

The immediate issue of the missing column could be resolved by runnint the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_option_value` 
ADD `label` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL 
COMMENT 'Option string as displayed to users - e.g. the label in an HTML OPTION tag.';
```

However, if this is messed up, there's a good chance there are other problems with your database, so you should check on that first.